# Use Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT to choose video up to some duration

Tags: android, android-intent, video

I have want to limit user to choose only videos with duration less then 60 seconds.

My code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("video/mp4");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
}
```

I already able to do that during capture video by camera with next code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 60);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have want to limit user to choose only videos with duration less then 60 seconds.

Then you will need to implement your own UI for this, using `MediaStore` to try to find videos that meet your requirements, then display them for selection in a list or grid or something. `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` does not support arbitrary filters ("duration less than 60 seconds", "length less than 500MB", "starring Amanda Seyfried", etc.).

> I already able to do that during capture video by camera with next code

No, you are able to *request* this. Camera apps that honor `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` *should* honor `EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT`. They do not *have* to honor `EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT`. The video that is recorded may be longer than your requested limit.